# Android phone can not connect to XAMPP sever that is installed on VMware

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

I installed  XAMPP server on VMware ( with Windows 8 ). The ipconfig command in VMware gives the following result:

[image]

Then I added the following lines to http-xampp.conf, where

```
192.168.1.51 : PC IP 

192.168.1.50  : (Android) phone IP.
```

[image]

Finally I tested

```
http://192.168.92.130/xampp/
```

both in my PC browser and VMware Windows browser, and the page opened  successfully, but when I try to open this URL in my phone browser ( which is connected to the same wi-fi router ), it  gives the following error:

Webpage not available
This webpage at

```
http://192.168.92.130/
```

could not be loaded because:

Would you please help me ?

Comment: have u conected ur mobile with server??

Comment: I mean to ur server via wi-fi ???

Comment: No, it's just connected to wifi. What should I do?

Comment: so r u sure that ur device is connected to ur server???

Comment: The device is connected to wifi. But it seems that it can not see the XAMPP on VMware

Comment: what is the ip of ur device after connecting to server???

Comment: The device IP is: 192.168.1.50

Comment: Does your device has Wifi connection or GPRS/3G Connection ?

Comment: from ur device id I can say that it is not connected to server...

Comment: It's ADSL wifi connection. I use it to share internet.

Comment: So, how I can connect the phone to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is hosting a private network for it and the Virtual machine. You will need to change the network adapter on the VmWare box so that it get an actual IP from your router.

Your phone and the virtual machine are on separate ranges.

Edit: The term is "Bridged Network"

http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-BAFA66C3-81F0-4FCA-84C4-D9F7D258A60A.html